# MIP SDK error while deploying in Azure - SSL failure Inner exception: [http_exception: 'WinHttpSendRequest' CorrelationId.Description=PolicyProfile

Tags: c#, microsoft-information-protection

MIP works good locally. But while deploying in azure, we are getting error like below.

SSL failure Inner exception: [http_exception: 'WinHttpSendRequest: 12030: The connection with the server was terminated abnormally'], CorrelationId=6b3dc820-a7a4-4dc0-8636-9dca3b529586, CorrelationId.Description=PolicyProfile, HttpRequest.Id={B0F01977-8904-49AC-AF7C-B1E7E43D8E0C}, HttpRequest.SanitizedUrl=https://dataservice.protection.outlook.com/PsorWebService/v1/ClientSyncFile/MipPolicies, NetworkError.Category=SSL

Unable to identify exactly. What could be the issue.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is specific to target .net framework version in azure. Updating the target .net framework version resolved the issue. Thank you.