# "SSL failure Inner exception. WindHttpSendRequest:12030" when running in Azure

Tags: azure-web-app-service, .net-4.7.2, microsoft-information-protection

I am working on labeling of documents using MIP SDK 1.7.133.
The code is working fine in local machine and IIS (windows). But when I run the labeling code in Azure App Service, I get the following error:

> "Message": "An error has occurred.",
> "ExceptionMessage": "SSL failure Inner exception: [http_exception: 'WinHttpSendRequest: 12030: The connection with the
> server was terminated abnormally'],
> CorrelationId=56acdff3-ec61-4723-8bee-21ea49f27334,
> CorrelationId.Description=PolicyProfile,
> HttpRequest.Id={6187BC6B-FF2E-419C-BB8D-34B828B5C105},
> HttpRequest.SanitizedUrl=https://dataservice.protection.outlook.com/PsorWebService/v1/ClientSyncFile/MipPolicies,
> NetworkError.Category=SSL",
> "ExceptionType": "Microsoft.InformationProtection.Exceptions.NetworkException",
> "StackTrace": "   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
> at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n...

The code before failure:

```
 public ProtectionManager(ProtectionParameters protectionParameters)
    {
        _appInfo = new ApplicationInfo()
        {
            ApplicationId = protectionParameters.ClientId,
            ApplicationName = protectionParameters.AppName,
            ApplicationVersion = protectionParameters.AppVersion
        };
        _protectionParameters = protectionParameters;
        _authDelegate = new AuthDelegateImplementation(_appInfo, _protectionParameters);
        var path = Path.Combine(
        Directory.GetParent(Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath)).FullName,
        Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "bin\\x64" : "bin\\x86");
        
        MIP.Initialize(MipComponent.File, path);
        
        Identity id = new Identity($"{_appInfo.ApplicationId}@{_protectionParameters.Tenant}");
        
        profile = CreateFileProfile(_appInfo);
        
        engine = CreateFileEngine(id);
    }

    private IFileProfile CreateFileProfile(ApplicationInfo appInfo)
    {
        string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).AbsolutePath);
        mipContext = MIP.CreateMipContext(appInfo, Path.Combine(appPath,"mip_data"), Microsoft.InformationProtection.LogLevel.Trace, null, null);
        // Initialize file profile settings to create/use local state.                
        var profileSettings = new FileProfileSettings(mipContext, CacheStorageType.InMemory, new ConsentDelegateImplementation());            
        var profile = Task.Run(async () => await MIP.LoadFileProfileAsync(profileSettings)).Result;
        return profile;

    }

    private IFileEngine CreateFileEngine(Identity identity)
    {
                 
        var engineSettings = new FileEngineSettings(identity.Email, _authDelegate, "", "en-US")
        {                
            Identity = identity,                                                          
        };            
        **var engine = Task.Run(async () => await profile.AddEngineAsync(engineSettings)).Result;**
        return engine;
    }
```

Would be glad to hear any thoughts.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody ran in to this yesterday and mentioned that changing the target .NET framework fixed the issue.

[MIP SDK error while deploying in Azure - SSL failure Inner exception: [http_exception: 'WinHttpSendRequest' CorrelationId.Description=PolicyProfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64788724/mip-sdk-error-while-deploying-in-azure-ssl-failure-inner-exception-http-exce/64790212#64790212)

You might comment on his post for specifics. I can add this to our documentation once I have details :)

Comment: This person is from my team)) That was incorrect suggestion about .NET Framework. It doesn't fix an issue.